# RewriteRule on PHP files and parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a website and I want it to be SEO Friendly.
I'm having extension of pages as `.php` and I want to hide it from url.
I'm also having two other pages names `abc.php` and `xyz.php` which gives output depending on ulr parameters.

So I want something like this:

`mydomain.com/pagename.php` to show as `mydomain.com/pagename`

`mydomain.com/abc.php?id=name` to show as `mydomain.com/abc/name`

`mydomain.com/xyz.php?id=name` to show as `mydomain.com/xyz/name`

Please help me to write `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` for that.

Comment: This is NOT a [Freecode.com](http://freecode.com/): [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

**Option 1**: Use `MultiViews` - then apache will pass requests to your php files even when the extension is omitted - and then deal with the rest inside php (parse `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`).

**Option 2**: Disable `MultiViews` and use URL rewriting:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(pagename|abc|xyz)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(pagename|abc|xyz)/([^/]+) $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i tried solution given by you,
RewriteRule ^(pagename|abc|xyz)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA] This part is working for me but 
RewriteRule ^(pagename|abc|xyz)/([^/]+) $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA] part is now working. 
i want it to be worked as mydomain.com/abc.php?id=name to show as mydomain.com/abc/name ,
and mydomain.com/xyz.php?id=name to show as mydomain.com/xyz/name
when i tried it it giving "error page not found"

Comment: this only transforms `mydomain.com/abc/name` into `mydomain.com/abc.php?id=name`, not the other way around. your php code should generate links differently if you want the links to appear nice in the resulting html.

Comment: +1 @poncha That's a valid answer. Redirecting the resource URL to a "pretty" URL that goes back to the same resource URL, is the wrong approach.

Comment: thank you,
can we write `multiple mod_rewrite rules` so that this will work as i want?
the solution i tried is only applicable for one page with which i can get **mydomain.com/abc/name** into **mydomain.com/abc.php?id=name**.
but if i want other page should work similar and i'll  **mydomain.com/xyz.php?id=name** to show as **mydomain.com/xyz/name** is not working properly.

Comment: @Balaji as i said before, if you want to change how your HTML works, you need to alter php that is creating it. this rewrite code will translate one-way (from "beautified" url to parameters), the other way should be done by php.